# Select records from a table with the latest 3 consecutive status as failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am needing to select Phone Numbers that have the latest 3 consecutive status as `Failed` or `Send_Failed`. Let me explain further with an example (Microsoft SQL Server)

My table:

```
| Phone Number Attempted | Date Sent | SMS Return Code |
|*456                    | 2020-11-17|     SEND_FAILED*|
|*456                    | 2020-11-16|     SEND_FAILED*|
|*456                    | 2020-11-15|     FAILED*     |
| 456                    | 2020-11-14|     DELIVERED   |
|*457                    | 2020-11-17|     SEND_FAILED*|
|*457                    | 2020-11-16|     SEND_FAILED*|
|*457                    | 2020-11-15|     SEND_FAILED*|
| 457                    | 2020-11-14|     SEND_FAILED |
| 455                    | 2020-11-17|     DELIVERED   |
| 455                    | 2020-11-16|     FAILED      |
| 455                    | 2020-11-15|     DELIVERED   |
| 455                    | 2020-11-14|     DELIVERED   |
| 454                    | 2020-11-17|     DELIVERED   |
| 454                    | 2020-11-16|     DELIVERED   |
| 454                    | 2020-11-15|     DELIVERED   |
| 454                    | 2020-11-14|     DELIVERED   |
| 453                    | 2020-11-17|     SEND_FAILED |
| 453                    | 2020-11-16|     SEND_FAILED |
| 452                    | 2020-11-17|     SEND_FAILED |
| 452                    | 2020-11-16|     SEND_FAILED |
| 452                    | 2020-11-15|     DELIVERED   |>
```

Expected result:

```
456
457
```

While below query it gets results very close to what I need, it fails since it also select record 452. Apparently my query fails to set the condition that the three more recent status must be a failed each of them.

```
select 
    i.[Phone Number Attempted], [SMS Return Code]
from 
    (select [Phone Number Attempted], [Date Sent] 
     from [MyTable]) i 
cross apply 
    (select top 3 *  
     from [MyTable] ti 
     where i.[Phone Number Attempted] = ti.[Phone Number Attempted]  
       and ti.[SMS Return Code] != 'DELIVERED') C
group by 
    i.[Phone Number Attempted], [SMS Return Code], C.[Date Sent]
having 
    MIN(C.[SMS Return Code]) !='DELIVERED' 
    and MAX(C.[SMS Return Code]) !='DELIVERED' 
    and count (*) >= 3
    and C.[Date Sent] = MAX(i.[Date Sent])
```

Comment: Your code would not run in MySQL.  Are you sure you are using that database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select distinct phone
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by phone order by date) as prev_status,
             lag(status, 2) over (partition by phone order by date) as prev2_status,
      from t
     ) t
where status in ('Failed', 'Send_Failed') and
      prev_status in ('Failed', 'Send_Failed') and
      prev2_status in ('Failed', 'Send_Failed') ;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. For some reason it does not work when there are cases when the more 6 status are DELIVERED an after SEND_FAILED are listed. I really needed the Ids where the 3 most recent consecutive status are either SEND_FAILED or FAILED

Comment: @John . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?  This query should not be sensitive to the number of delivered in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Below query gave me the right results for my own question

```
select 
    
      distinct A.[Phone Number Attempted]
     
    

 from 
(
Select  distinct  [Phone Number Attempted],  [SMS Return Code], [Date Sent]

        ,LAG([SMS Return Code]) over (partition by [Phone Number Attempted] order by [Sent Date]) as prev_status
        ,lag([SMS Return Code], 2) over (partition by  [Phone Number Attempted] order by [Sent Date]) as prev2_status

from  [MyTable] ) A 

where 
    prev_status in  ('FAILED', 'SEND_FAILED') and
    prev2_status   in ('FAILED', 'SEND_FAILED') and 
    [SMS Return Code] in ('FAILED', 'SEND_FAILED') and  not exists 
(Select 1 from [MyTable] B where A.[Phone Number Attempted] =B.[Phone Number Attempted] and B.[Sent Date] > A.[Sent Date])
```